# How to set background image so that header part is fixed upon scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the background image using CSS but the it covers the content on title bar.
I have fixed the position of header. But when I scroll the image it covers the header Can anyone tell how to fix it. I have attached a screenshot upon scrolling the header is not fixed.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
        <title></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <section id="title-bar">
          <h1> Visualizer </h1>
            <a href="url">Login</a>
          <a href="url">Registration</a>
            <a href="url">Home</a>
        </section>
        <section id="intro">
          <div class="bg-image"></div>
          <div class="bg-image"></div>
        </section>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Upon scrolling the image come above the title-bar but I am trying to get image inside the title bar.
CSS  code

'''

```
#title-bar{
  background-color: #9E9D89;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  overflow:  visible;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#title-bar h1{
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  float:  left;
  color: white;
}
#title-bar a{
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
body{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#title-bar a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #185ADB;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}  
#intro {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 100px;

}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("../images/image1.jpg");
  
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  
  /* Full height */
  height: 400px; 

  
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;  
}
```

```
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1tFP.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply a [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) higher than the section.

As per MDN:

> The `z-index` CSS property sets the z-order of a [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) element and its descendants or flex items. **Overlapping elements with a larger z-index cover those with a smaller one.**

In our case, simply apply `z-index: 1` to `#title-bar` will make it overlap the section, since its `z-index` is default to 0.

```css
#title-bar {
  background-color: #9E9D89;
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}

#title-bar h1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  float: left;
  color: white;
}

#title-bar a {
  margin-right: 50px;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  float: right;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#title-bar a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: #185ADB;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

#intro {
  margin: 0px;
  padding-top: 100px;
}

.bg-image {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0fdacb141bca7fa57c392b5f03872176?s=48&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1");
  /* Add the blur effect */
  filter: blur(0px);
  -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
  /* Full height */
  height: 400px;
  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  /* background-position: center; */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <section id="title-bar">
    <h1> Visualizer </h1>
    <a href="url">Login</a>
    <a href="url">Registration</a>
    <a href="url">Home</a>
  </section>
  <section id="intro">
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
    <div class="bg-image"></div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```